# Editing inline cell changes same row number on first page

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing

I'm starting out with a blank grid, then have an icon to browse for a spreadsheet that can import a list of users.  My grid is set up like this:

```
        $grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        height: 'auto',
        width: '100%',
        colNames: ['Last Name', 'First Name', 'Username', 'Email', 'Phone', ...],
        colModel: [
            { name:'lastName', width:45, sortable:false, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','nc']},
                editable:true, editoptions:{maxlength:20}
            },
            { name:'firstName', width:45, sortable:false, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']},
                editable:true, editoptions:{maxlength:20}
            },
            { name:'username', width:60,
                editable:false, editoptions:{maxlength:50}
            },
            { name:'email', width:50, sortable:true, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']},
                editable:true, editoptions:{maxlength:50}, editrules:{email:true}
            },
            { name:'phone', width:35, sortable:true, searchoptions:{sopt:['cn']},
                editable:true, editoptions:{maxlength:10}
            },
            ...
        ],
        shrinkToFit: true,
        forceFit: true,
        autowidth: true,
        rowTotal: 2000,
        rowList: [20, 30, 40, 50],
        loadonce: true,
        gridview: true,
        pager: pagerId,
        sortname: 'Last Name',
        viewrecords: true,
        altRows: true,
        altclass: 'rowAltClass',
        ignoreCase: true,
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        editurl:'clientArray',
        caption: '<div class="bulkUserCaption"><span>Users To Be Added</span></div>',
        beforeEditCell: function(rowId, cellName, value) {
            prevCellVal = value;
        },
        afterSaveCell: function(rowId, cellName, value, iRow, iCol) {
            console.log("afterSaveCell");
        },
        beforeSaveCell: function(rowId, cellName, value, iRow, iCol) {
            console.log("beforeSaveCell");
        },
        beforeSubmitCell: function(rowId, cellName, value, iRow, iCol) {
            console.log("beforeSubmitCell");
            // Error check the email for a valid email address.
            if (cellName == "email") {
                email = value;
                // Perform some error check on email.
                if (isValidEmail(email)) {
                    $grid.jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'email', email);
                    $grid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowId).email = email;
                } else {
                    // Alert user to email error
                }
            }

        },
        afterSubmitCell: function(response, rowId, cellName, value, iRow, iCol) {
            console.log("afterSubmitCell");
        },
        beforeSelectRow: function(rowId) {
            $(this).jqGrid('setSelection', rowId, true);
            return false; // allow selection (true) or unselection (false)
        },
        onSelectRow: function(rowId) {
            if (rowId && rowId !== lastCell) {
                $(this).jqGrid('saveCell', rowIdx, lastCol);
                lastCell = rowId;
            }
        },
        ondblClickRow: function(rowId, iRow, iCol) {
            $(this).jqGrid('editCell', iRow, iCol, true);
            lastCell = rowId;
            lastCol = iCol;
            rowIdx = iRow * pgNum;
        },
        loadComplete: function() {
            preserveFilters($(this));
        }
    });
```

I have a function called doImport() that handles the importing of the spreadsheet, transforms the data a little, the loads the grid.

```
        if (json.msg == "success") {
             // Reload the grid with the new data
            $grid.setGridParam({'datatype':'local', 'data': json.rows}).trigger('reloadGrid');
        } else {
           // Show alert message
        }
```

I get a nice grid of users but I need to be able to edit them if there are any errors in the data.  I am able to edit, but if I'm on page 2, for example, and I'm editing a user's email address on row 20, when I hit enter to make the change, it puts the new data in the same column and same row, but on page 1.

Not sure where I've gone wrong here, but I can't get the edit to work as expected.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have unique ids in the grid. Usually this is done in jsonReader (in your case localReader) grid property  or you can set it using the key:true property in colModel field. This will grand you editing without problems.

Comment: I ended up including a unique row ID back with the data when the grid gets loaded and set it's key:true property in the colModel field.  Thanks for the info!  This worked for me!